# How to share progress updates through JNI?

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, java-native-interface, shared-memory

How can I display in Java the progress of a computation done in C++?

The java application calls a C++ method through JNI, how could I share, let's say, a `double progress;` between the java application and the C++ method?

I don't really know how multithreading is handled in JNI.

Moreover, the target platforms are Windows and Linux.

Comment: I don't think you need to share memory, you just need to call a Java method from C++ and pass a double `currentProgress / total` which will give you a double value in the range of 0-1.

Comment: @ddriver I'm calling c++ code _from_ Java. The first call would start the algorithm (on a new thread, either java or C++). Now, following your suggestion, how can the second call access a `currentProgress` variable if the two threads do not know each other?

Comment: @ddriver Or, let me put it this way, you suggest calling a method to access the `currentProgress`. What I don't follow from your suggestion is: who is modifing this `currentProgress`, thus, who's running the actual computation?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches to reporting progress from the native side to Java.

One is to call methods on a Java object from C++ via JNI. You might pass the object in the C++ computation method itself, or in some other method.

Another is to share a region of memory with a direct ByteBuffer. In Java, call [ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect%28int%29) to create the buffer. Pass the buffer to C++, and there use [GetDirectBufferAddress()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#get_direct_buffer_address) to get its memory address. In C++, write directly to the buffer. In Java, poll for changes.

Comment: Aah, that's what @ddriver was suggesting. I'll try that.